# Keyboard shortcut to switch to the desktop background

Tags: windows

I have a Windows XP machine, and one of my applications has this annoying habit of hiding behind other applications and take the focus away, so there is no way for me to take back the control. I would often have to end that application from [Task Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Manager) in order to get my mouse control back.

Is there a keyboard shortcut that allows me to switch to the desktop background, and hence I can close the apps to regain my mouse focus?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you push <kbd>Window</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, other windows hide, and you get focus on the desktop.

Answer (score 5):

The Windows key + d will show the desktop (effectively minimizing all applications).  I am not sure if that will help in your situation, as you seem to have a modal dialog up with no way to close it.