# Windows 8 keyboard shortcut to go to the desktop

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [Keyboard Shortcut to Switch to the Desktop Background](https://superuser.com/questions/83555/keyboard-shortcut-to-switch-to-the-desktop-background) 
>   [What are the new shortcuts for Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/466789/what-are-the-new-shortcuts-for-windows-8)

The <kbd>Windows</kbd> key is a shortcut to Metro. Is there an equivalent type shortcut to show your desktop?

If not, is there some way I can set this up?

Comment: Although closed, are you able to mark an answer?

Comment: @Luke Ah sorry, when I originally had tried to accept it enough time hadn't passed yet and then I just forgot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> will show your desktop

Comment: Oh man ... something tells me this is probably a shortcut that's been around a while. I've just never needed it as much as I do with getting out of Metro.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, the Windows key will toggle between the Start Screen and your desktop as well.

[windows-8](/questions/tagged/windows-8) [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) [efficiency](/questions/tagged/efficiency)

Comment: I was looking for straight to Desktop. The Windows key just toggles Metro on and off (to the last thing you had open).

Comment: Got it :) Thanks for clarifying for me. Just in case it's helpful, here's a link to almost any shortcut you might ever need... [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126449?wa=wsignin1.0)